# Upload Video to YouTube Using C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, video, upload, youtube, unity-game-engine

I Needed upload Video to you tube.It supports for only **Android Mobiles**.I am new from unity so how to upload video to you tube please help me.I am using unity 4.2.2 Version.

The Below Code is Works for Upload Video & also doen't know name spaces also:

```
             YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("whatwill come here ?",
            "my api key",
            "my youtube login email", "my youtube login password");
        YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

        Video newVideo = new Video();

        newVideo.Title = "test 1";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Gaming", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "test 1 , test 2";
        newVideo.Description = "test 3 test 4";
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("tag 1, tag 2",
                      YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\test.avi", "video/quicktime");         
        Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I doesn't have any idea, I search in Google also but no use so I posted to this site. @soner Gonul.

Comment: Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Direct_Upload

Comment: I Am Trying to Above Code But I doesn't Namespaces also.@Soner Gonul.

Comment: Sorry, but "I doesn't namespaces" is not a sentence. I'm guessing either you didn't download the client library or you need to add a reference to it?

Comment: Yes , Which Client library I can Download for this? ,@Gareth

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't imported the appropriate namespaces that your code relies on. The documentation linked in the post comments refer to the Youtube Data API, which you can get [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list). Install the API correctly so that you can use the namespace in your Unity3D project.

I must warn you, after previously trying to use their Google Analytics API with Unity3D, you're in for a lot of trouble. These libraries are intended for .NET and Unity is running Mono 2.0. In all likelyhood, they won't work verbatim.